# can't added my object to to ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, object, arraylist

i tried to add an object to ArrayList ?
but ican't whyyyyyy ?

```
ArrayList<Patient> emer; 

Patient p = new Patient(); 

p.setName(jTextField1.getText());
p.setSurname(jTextField2.getText());
p.setGender(jRadioButton1.getText()); } p.setBooldType(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() + ""); p.setEntarnceDay(jComboBox2.getSelectedItem() + "/" + jComboBox3.getSelectedItem() + "/" + jComboBox4.getSelectedItem()); p.setFee(Integer.parseInt(jTextField8.getText())); 
emer.add(p);
```

Comment: what is this curly bracket in the middle??

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't initialized your `emer` and are probably getting "local variable not initialized" error.

```
ArrayList<Patient> emer;
```

What you need is to initialize `emer` with a new array list instance.

```
ArrayList<Patient> emer = new ArrayList<Patient>();
```

Or better yet:

```
List<Patient> emer = new ArrayList<Patient>();
```

Comment: Thnx for your answer I have initialized the ArrayList also the net beans didnt give me an error but the arraylist didnt take any object 
The size of arrayList is always 1 that is my problem